# Sql: Select where a condition is true for all types

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table defined and populated as follows:

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE
(
    ProjectId INT,
    EmployeeId INT,
    SomeTypeId INT,
    IsExpired BIT,
    IsWarning BIT,
    IsIncomplete BIT
)

--all incomplete...
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES (1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES (1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES (1, 1, 3, 0, 0, 1)

--two warnings...
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES (1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES (1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES (1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0)

--two expirations...
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES (1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES (1, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES (1, 3, 3, 1, 0, 0)
```

I want to return distinct ProjectId, EmployeeId pairs with any warnings or expirations:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ProjectId, EmployeeId FROM @Temp WHERE IsWarning = 1 OR IsExpired = 1
```

No problem.

However, I'd like to also return ProjectId, EmployeeId pairs where IsWarning = 0 and IsExpired = 0 and IsIncomplete = 1, but this must be true for all SomeTypeId's (1, 2, 3). In other words, no warnings, no expirations, just incomplete for all categories.

SomeTypeId Fks to a lookup table. Right now there are only 3 entries, but there could be more in the future.

Any ideas?

I would expect ProjectId, EmployeeId (1, 1) to be returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses `MAX` and `MIN` to see to that all values are the same; one needs to add a `+ 0` to each bit to make it available to normal numeric aggregate functions (like `MIN`/`MAX`/`SUM`/...)

```
SELECT ProjectId, EmployeeId
FROM Temp
GROUP BY ProjectId, EmployeeId
HAVING MAX(IsWarning    + 0) = 0
   AND MAX(IsExpired    + 0) = 0
   AND MIN(IsIncomplete + 0) = 1
```

[An SQLfiddle for testing](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/27b07/2).

Comment: This is not working for the scenario where `all 1,2,3 SomeTypeId`  records having `IsWarning = 0 and IsExpired = 0 and IsIncomplete = 1`

Comment: @Kaf Hm? I may very well have misunderstood the question, but I can't see what case would not work. Could you give a counter example?

Comment: [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/07d3b/1) I simply commented 3rd record yet it is still selected.

Comment: @Kaf I read that as that it has to be true for all values for SomeTypeId in that ProjectId/EmployeeId group, that is what I solved. If you're right about exactly 1,2,3 being required, my solution will as you point out not do that.

Comment: Your assumption is correct. SomeTypeIds 1,2,3, (and possibly more) will always be present. I should have stated that better in the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure from your question if you mean that you want those results in the SAME query, or you want an entirely new query. Assuming the latter, your query would be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ProjectId, EmployeeId FROM @Temp WHERE (IsWarning = 0 AND IsExpired = 0 AND IsIncomplete = 1)
```

Assuming the former, it would be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ProjectId, EmployeeId FROM @Temp WHERE (IsWarning = 1 OR IsExpired = 1)
```

OR (IsWarning = 0 AND IsExpired = 0 AND IsIncomplete = 1)

Comment: Well... Not exactly. For the incomplete case, I need to make sure your first query is true, but over all types defined by SomeTypeId.

Answer (score 0):

Try this assuming you have no duplicate records;

Please note that `union` is added *assuming* you still need to select data *`WHERE IsWarning = 1 OR IsExpired = 1`*. If you don't need them simply remove it.

[SQL-DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ef464/1)

```
;with cte as (
  select projectid, employeeid,
         case when sometypeid in (1,2,3) and 
                   IsWarning = 0 and IsExpired = 0 and IsIncomplete = 1
              then 1 else 0 end x
  from temp  
)
select projectid, employeeid 
from cte
group by projectId, employeeid
having sum(x) >= 3
union
select projectid, employeeid 
from Temp 
where IsWarning = 1 or IsExpired = 1
```